# How to fill ListView Adapter items with data from FirebaseDatabase [Android Studio]

Tags: java, android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building an app which shows data from **firebase database** in `ListView` adapter, but the listview doesn't fill with data. Database works. I tried this with `textview.setText` method on specially created layout.

```
public class MainActivityListFragment extends ListFragment {
    private ArrayList<typ> typy;
    private typAdapter typAdapter;
    String tytul1, rodzaj1, godzina1, typ1, kurs1;

    DatabaseReference mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference mmecz1 = mRootRef.child("mecz1");
    DatabaseReference mtytul1 = mmecz1.child("tytul1");
    DatabaseReference mrodzaj1 = mmecz1.child("rodzaj1");
    DatabaseReference mgodzina1 = mmecz1.child("godzina1");
    DatabaseReference mtyp1 = mmecz1.child("typ1");
    DatabaseReference mkurs1 = mmecz1.child("kurs1");

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        typy = new ArrayList<typ>();
        typy.add(new typ(tytul1, rodzaj1, godzina1, typ1, kurs1));
        typy.add(new typ("Portugalia - Islandia", "wygrana drużyny", "21:00", "1", "1.50"));
        typAdapter = new typAdapter(getActivity(), typy);
        setListAdapter(typAdapter);

        getListView().setDivider(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), android.R.color.black));
        getListView().setDividerHeight(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mtytul1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String text1 = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                tytul1 = text1;
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"No internet connection",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        mrodzaj1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String text2 = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                rodzaj1=text2;
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        mgodzina1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String text3 = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                godzina1 = text3;
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        mtyp1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String text4 = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                typ1 = text4;
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        mkurs1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String text5 = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                kurs1 = text5;
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your `typAdapter` extend `FirebaseListAdapter`?

Comment: No. I didn't use Firebase adapters. I created custom ListView adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a FirebaseListAdapter.

Add this dependency to your project:

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'
```

Then follow these instruction from their Github readme:

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md

Answer (score 0):

This isn't working because the values in your Strings are null when the `typy.add()` is executed. 
For achieving what you want, you have to figure out a way to add your strings in `typy.add()` inside your `.addValueEventListener` and calling     `typAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` later.

You can also use Firebase UI, which has FirebaseListAdapters, if your ListView is simple.